# Android: How to set a default ListView with sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, sharedpreferences, default

What I want to do is:

When my application loads for the first time, I want it to load with my default ListView that has 1 item inside named "New Item", and later on if changes will be made to my ListView, I want to have a button named "Default settings", to return the ListView back to be "1 item named "New Item",

From what I have heard I need to use Shared Preferences for it, but i have no clue where to begin.

Thanks for you assistance.

Comment: http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.be/2012/03/android-preferenceactivity.html

Answer (score 0):

Your question is **very** vague. You will probably use SharedPreferences, however it is only a storage mechanism.

I would not recommend using a reset button on the list, but if you want to I'll go along with it.

First of all you would need to create an ArrayAdapter and load it from SharedPreferences when data changes. There are a ton of tutorials.

On your ListView use addHeaderView() and addFooterView() to add you "+ New Item" rows or they'll play about with your adapter. Basically just notify the ArrayAdapter when new items are added or the list deleted.

If you need more details, there are plenty of in-depth tutorials if you Google for it :)

Answer (score 0):

the question you explicitly requested for does not require `SharedPreferences`, what it requires is a method in your ListView's custom `Adapter`.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<String> content;

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(content.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    private void revert() {
        ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<String>();
        content.add("New Item");
        this.content = content;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Then in your button's `onClick` method, you simply call this revert method.